# Tune performance of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I've got an array which I access serval times in my code. The content of my array looks something like this:

> ... "-", "200", "Connection", "True", "-", "tcp", ...

My goal here is to assign those vaules to a dedicated variable for each object in my array. Right now I have realized this with the code below:

```
if (myArray[2] != null) {
            if (myArray[2].length >= 2) {
                a = myArray[2];
        }
    } 

    if (myArray[5] != null && myArray[10] != null) {
        if (myArray[5].length >= 2 && myArray[10].length >= 2) {
            var b = myArray[5] + " " + myArray[10];
            bOutput = b;
        }
    }
```

As you can see I'm always accessing the array, check for the length of the object (I dont want the dedicated value set if the value is only a "-"). My array contains approximately 40 objects - Those 40 objects need to be stored in dedicated variables.

Since I'm having performance problems my guess here is that it's caused due to the assignment and my checks.

Is there a better and faster way to access/check and/or assign the values to a dedicated variable?

Comment: Not really, but you can make it easier to read: 

`let a = myArray[2]; a = a && a.length>2?a:"";`
`let b = myArray[5] ||""; b+= " " + (myArray[10] || ""); if (!b.length>5) b="";`

Answer (score 0):

I think the code that you wrote in question shouldn't have a performance problem .
but you can use some techniques. for example
   1.if you check all items of the array more than once and your array doesn't changed during the process , it's better to filter your array.

```
var filteredData = data.filter( item => item != null && item.length > 2);
```

2.you can use metadata array in which you can save the result of condition.

```
var myArray = []
var metadata = []
function addToArray(item) {
  myArray.push(item)
  metadata.push(item != null && item.length > 2)
}

if (metadata[2]) {
  a = myArray[2]
}

if (metadata[5] && metadata[10]) {
  var b = myArray[5] + ' ' + myArray[10]
}
```